# Invalid field override named 'email'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I am trying to override two properties of FOSUserBundle's User mapping.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
...
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"emailCanonical", "zone"},
 *     errorPath="email",
 *     message="This email address is already in use."
 * )
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false)),
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="emailCanonical", length=255, unique=false, nullable=false))
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    ...
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except when I generate accessors: `Invalid field override named 'email'`

The error is thrown here:

```
// Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo

public function setAttributeOverride($fieldName, array $overrideMapping)
{
    if ( ! isset($this->fieldMappings[$fieldName])) {
        throw MappingException::invalidOverrideFieldName($this->name, $fieldName);
    }
```

Here, `$this->fieldMappings` only contains the fields of my child User and not of the parent (mapped superclass).

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 7):

The way I managed to fix this issue with **Invalid field override named [field] for class [class]** was to also add the overwritten attribute in the class I overwritten it.

I'm using version **Symfony v2.7.8** and **Doctrine v1.6.1**.

Example:

```
<?php

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             type="string",
 *             name="username_canonical",
 *             length=255,
 *             unique=false
 *         )
 *     )
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="username_canonical", length=255, unique=false)
     */
    protected $usernameCanonical;
    ...
}
```

Comment: In this case, another error appears "Duplicate mapping for column email"

Comment: In my case, I had AttributesOverride, and this error would show up because one of my new relations added to totally unrelated entity (another entity, not the one mentioned in the error message) was wrong. For instance, I moved an entity to a different namespace, and it couldn't find it anymore. So I had to fix my OneToOne relation to have the correct namespace...go figure.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You're right, there is mapping info in FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/User.orm.xml...

```
<mapped-superclass name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">
    ...
    <field name="usernameCanonical" column="username_canonical" type="string" length="255" unique="true" />
    <field name="email" column="email" type="string" length="255" />
```

Just guessing: Maybe this xml orm config is not parsed properly? Or maybe you need to do the overwrites in xml too?

Comment: Well, the FOSUserBundle docs seem to suggest otherwise https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md#replacing-the-mapping-of-the-bundle

Comment: Did you try to put your mapping overwrites in xml?

Comment: I tried with converting annotation to xml on my side. Still same problem. Still trying to figure out how to fix this on this older project of mine.

Comment: I ended up taking all the code from the base class. I created my own entity without extending that base class, but by implementing `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface` and `FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupableInterface` and creating a db mapping with no overrides that changes the things I need to change. Really not ideal, but all the issues I tried to search were left open or unresolved. Not clean, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but i found a sulution, at least it worked for me, maybe it would be helpful for someone else.

Well, i had the same issue and i'm using a custom manager for the fos_user, in the declaration file config.yml under doctrine entity_manager custom manager i declared the mapping to FOS_userBundle, BUT what was missing is to tell FOS_user that we use a diffrent manager and that's by adding :

fos_user:
----    db_driver: orm
----    **model_manager_name: MyCustom_Manager**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive an old post. What worked for me was to remove the ORM annotation on the field and ensure the name in AttributeOverride was the same as the field name being overridden.

E.g. the ff ORM annotation

```php
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="username_canonical", length=255, unique=false)
 */
protected $usernameCanonical;
```

Should become:

```php
@ORM\AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
    column=@ORM\Column(
        type="string",
        name="username_canonical",
        length=255,
        unique=false
    )
)
```

Then, remove the ORM annotation to ensure we don't get a "Duplicate mapping for column" error. The final class looks like:

```php
<?php

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="usernameCanonical",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             type="string",
 *             name="username_canonical",
 *             length=255,
 *             unique=false
 *         )
 *     )
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $usernameCanonical;
}
```